# ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a checkbox to a webpage with react. its value is in useWalletCreadit. after that, by submitting the form it should post it to api.py file. this is post method:

```
submitForm: (pay_method, useWalletCredit, onSuccess, onFailure) => {
    console.log(this.useWalletCredit);
    dispatch({type: 'START_LOADING'});
    return PrivateApi.post('cart/pay', {
        'submit-pay': 'submit',
        web: 'true',
        'pay-method': pay_method,
        'useWalletCredit_': this.useWalletCredit,
    })
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({type: 'END_LOADING'});
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(res.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch({type: 'END_LOADING'});
            if (onFailure) onFailure(error);
        })
},
```

it raise this error:

> CartPay.js:532 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'useWalletCredit' of undefined

Comment: The `submitForm` method takes a parameter named `useWalletCredit`, but the code within the method ignores that argument and uses `this.useWalletCredit`. Why?

Comment: I honestly tried to avoid asking that question because I wanted to help solve the problem first. But yes, that was very puzzling. Using the parameter is the easier thing to do, and is very much the intuitive one too.

Comment: useWalletCreadit defined in states at the top. this is why it needs this, to point to useWalletState. @HereticMonkey

Comment: If useWalletCredit is stored in state, why not remove that parameter you have on submitForm?

Comment: cause I need it to be posted to api.py @NathanHall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1218980)

Answer (score 0):

If this is component/class and you arrow function, `this` will be `undefined` because there will be no parent context to use.

use normal function:

```
submitForm: function(pay_method, useWalletCredit, onSuccess, onFailure) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: useWalletCreadit defined in states at the top. this is why it needs this, to point to useWalletState.

Comment: @MHB can you show your whole code then? `this` is definitelly undefined, as error say.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an arrow function. Arrow functions do not create their own `this` object, instead inheriting from their outer scope.

It's also weird (to me, without further context) that you do not have any `this` object to work with, as I'd expect that the value of `useWalletCredit` would be `undefined`.

You needn't have this problem though, since you can simply refer to `useWalletCredit` directly.

Comment: useWalletCreadit defined in states at the top. this is why it needs this, to point to useWalletState.

Comment: Please post the contents of the entire file, or maybe just the skeleton of the enclosing component and the state. Are you using a class component or a functional one? I'll need more information than you're providing.

Comment: Besides, you'll have to access a state property from the state itself rather than from the `this` object. I fail to see how you can do that though, since `this` is undefined. I'll definitely need more information.